# how to setstate after saga async request

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga in my project. 
I used redux-thunk before, so i can't setState ends of some async request. like

```
this.props.thunkAsync()
  .then(){
    this.setState({ '' });
  }
```

Since thunk returns promise, i could use 'then'.
But i can't do this with saga, because saga doesn't return promise.
So i did it in componentWillReceiveProps by checking flag props (like REQUEST_SUCCESS,REQUEST_WAITING...) has been changed. 
I think it's not good way to solve this problem.

So.. My question is how can i do some works when async request ends in redux-saga!

Comment: you can put the react's state in redux state so that you can set the state in saga itself and make use of the redux state in this component.

Comment: i thought about that.. thanks! But what if i want to call some function that only works locally?

Comment: If you are using redux to manage state, then you can fire an action and handle it in your reducer to set state.

Comment: @godsenal you should most probably move those functions to saga if you can.

Comment: @AnandS thanks! But what if i want to change inline style after async request end? Should i move this style object(or some local variable) to my redux state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every api call you make is processed as an async request but handled using a generator function in a saga.

So, After a successful api call, you can do the following possible things.

1. **Make another api call like**

> ```
> function* onLogin(action) {
>   try {
>     const { userName, password } = action;
>     const response = yield call(LoginService.login, userName, password);
>     yield put(LoginService.loginSuccess(response.user.id));
>     const branchDetails = yield call(ProfileService.fetchBranchDetails, response.user.user_type_id);
>     yield put(ProfileActions.fetchBranchDetailsSuccess(branchDetails));
>   } catch (error) {
>     yield put(ProfileActions.fetchUserDetailsError(error));
>   }
> }
> ```

2. **Pass a Callback after successfull api**

   ```
   onLoginClick() {
     const { userName, password } = this.state;
     this.props.login(userName, password, this.onLoginSuccess);
   }

   onLoginSuccess(userDetails) {
     this.setState({ userDetails });
   }

   function *onLogin(action) {
     try {
        const { userName, password, onLoginSuccess } = action;
        const response = yield call(LoginService.login, userName, password);
        if (onLoginSuccess) {
            onLoginSuccess(response);
        }

        yield put(LoginService.loginSuccess(response.user.id));
        const branchDetails = yield call(ProfileService.fetchBranchDetails, 
        response.user.user_type_id);
        yield put(ProfileActions.fetchBranchDetailsSuccess(branchDetails));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(ProfileActions.fetchUserDetailsError(error));
    }
   ```

   }
3. **Update Reducer State and get from props by mapStateToProps**

   ```
   yield put(LoginService.loginSuccess(response.user.id));        
   @connect(
       state => ({
           usedDetails: state.user.get('usedDetails'),
       })
   )
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
       const { usedDetails } = nextProps;
       return {
           usedDetails
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

> But i can't do this with saga, because saga doesn't return promise

`Redux-saga` is slightly different from `thunk` since it is process manager, not simple middleware: `thunk` performs reaction only on fired actions, but `saga` has its own "process" (Formally callback tick domain) and can manipulate with actions by effects.

Usual way to perform async actions with `redux-saga` is splitting original actions to `ACTION_REQUEST`, `ACTION_SUCCESS` and `ACTION_FAILURE` variants. Then reducer accepts only SUCCESS/FAILURE actions, and maybe REQUEST for [optimistic updates](https://dzone.com/articles/practical-reactjs-and-redux-optimistic-updates-par).

In that case, your `saga` process can be like following

```
function* actionNameSaga(action) {
    try {    
        const info = yield call(fetch, { params: action.params }
        yield put('ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS', info)
    } catch(err) {
        yield put('ACTION_NAME_FAILURE', err)
    }

function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery('ACTION_NAME', actionNameSaga)
}
```

Keep in mind that `yield` operation itself is not about promise waiting - it just delegates async waiting to saga process manager.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem...

My solution was wrapping the dispatch in a promise and call the resolve and reject in a saga function...

I created a hook to wrap the dispatch. You can see my example here: 
https://github.com/ricardocanelas/redux-saga-promise-example

I hope that can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. From component props you call the saga method and pass the function you want to execute after success or failure, like below

```
export function* login({ payload }) {
  const url = 'localhost://login.json';

 try {
    const response = yield call(App_Service, { url, method: 'GET' });
 if (response.result === 'ok' && response.data.body) {
    yield put(fetchDataActionCreators.getLoginSuccess(response.data.body));
    //function passed as param from component, pass true if success
    payload.callback(true);
  }


 } catch (e) {
        //function passed as param from component, pass false if failure
    payload.callback(false);
    console.log(e);
  }
}


export function* watchLogin() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(LOGIN);
    yield* login(action);
  }
}



export default function* () {
  yield all([
    fork(watchLogin)
  ]);
}
```

> In component call call setState method in the function you pass to saga as param

```
login() {
    // store
    this.props.getServiceDetails({
       callback:(success) => this.onLoginSuccess(success)
    })
  }



onLoginSuccess = (success) => {
    this.setState({
       login:success
    })
    alert('login '+success)
  }
```