# ReactJS / Redux call to dispatch action in other reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

How to dispatch action in other reducer.
For example i create reducer `LogsReducer` with switch case `ADD_LOG` and `REMOVE_LOG`. Code:

```
const addLog = (text) => ({type: 'ADD_LOG', text});
const removeLog = (id) => ({type: 'REMOVE_LOG', id});

const logsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_LOG':
       // todo
    case 'REMOVE_LOG':
       // todo
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And i add `logsReducer` to `combineReducers`.
To dispatch action i call this inside `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
dispatch(addLog('sample log'));
dispatch(removeLog(2);
```

And here question. How to allow to dispatch message from outside of logs reducer. For example from fetch response in other reducer eg. `contactReducer`?

Comment: All actions are sent to all reducers, so if the `action.type` is `ADD_LOG`, the `contactReducer` can also `switch` on it.

Comment: The only question you have to ask yourself is if your actions have to run in a certain order, if not, then @DavinTryon his answer is the one you need, if they do have to run in a certain sequence then you will need a middleware of some kind

Comment: Yep, but contactReducer is a diffrent reducer. And it dont have this case in `switch`. You know, i want to log user events and push it into state to key `logs` (logsReducer)

Comment: @icepickle Ohhh maybe middleware is a answer, i check it

Comment: But, if they do not have anything to do with eachother, then shouldn't you rather handle the logging inside your dispatcher? I don't see how the reducers can help you out? Can you add what you want to log, and where you want to log it? Maybe it might be better to create a higher order function that wraps your dispatchers?

Comment: Try not to do too much work in the reducer. If it is work you want to do asynchronously, then I'd recommend looking into redux-thunk or redux-saga. These provide a better place to do the computation.

Answer (score 2):

> How to allow to dispatch message from outside of logs reducer. For example from fetch response in other reducer eg. contactReducer?

Usually presence of asynchronous API calls or action dispatching queue meant that presentation/domain logic is consists of **process**, so process-manager is needed for resolve that task.

General solution is [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), which combines middleware and live process manager. With using `saga`, components just notify about logical happened action, and then saga performs API calls, produce new actions and even do [Optimistic updates](https://www.guidesmiths.com/en/news-and-blog/anatomy-of-a-react-application-optimistic-updates-22).

Also, with `redux+saga` approach your web-application automatically become full-stack Event-Sourced application: by writing front-end code you will get also isomorphic back-end code (If use some tool like that https://github.com/reimagined/resolve )

See practices with using saga [Infinite loop with redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993560/infinite-loop-with-redux-saga/44066279#44066279) and [how to setstate after saga async request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427001/how-to-setstate-after-saga-async-request/47429169#47429169)